# Categories in Customize window in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap

Could you tell me how to add new category of commands in *Commands* tab in *Customize* window in ArcGIS 10?

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/customizing-the-ui/about-configuring-the-user-interface.htm

Comment: If you are able to develop ArcMap Add Ins (using arcobjects and C# for example) you can define new catagories and assign for example custom buttons and tools. But I don't think there is a way to do that with acrgis standard tools. Please give some more information why you want to do that. So maybe someone could propose an alternative to you.

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible without adding new Add In into ArcMap. Just create a category to let others upload Add Ins into it.

Answer (score 2):

Those categories are instantiated when either a built in Add-in from ESRI is implemented or you install a third party Add-in.

From a coding viewpoint you would want to look at the config.esriaddin file and look for the commands. All commands will have a category tag and that catagory will be created in the Arcmap commands tab when you install that add-in.